# MS-Access - update column using results from joining another table

Tags: ms-access, join, sql-update, ms-access-2013, calculated-columns

I need to update the Amounts.Amt_lcy by multiplying the Amt_fcy column with the corresponding Fx_rates.Rate by joining the two tables on Data.

```
*Amounts*

Data        |    Amt_fcy    |  Amt_lcy  
31/03/2018            10              
30/04/2018            15    


*Fx_rates*

Data        |  Rate  
31/03/2018      2.5
30/04/2018      3.1
```

My query is the following:

update Amounts set Amt_lcy=(select Amounts.Amt_fcy*Fx_rates.Rate from Amounts left join Fx_rates on Amounts.Data=Fx_rates.Data)

I must be doing some basic mistake, because I get the 'Operation must use an updateable query' error.
Any help would be most welcome

Comment: Do you have a reason to update those amounts instead of keeping a rates history table and calculate 'on the fly' ?

Comment: Actually, I work on a different data structure, I just used this simplified example so I can understand what I am doing wrong on the real thing. Thx :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common issue.

In an update query in Access, all columns in any query, including subqueries but excluding `EXISTS` clauses, needs to be updateable.

Since you're calculating `Amounts.Amt_fcy*Fx_rates.Rate` in a subquery, and that's not updateable, the query fails.

This query can be rewritten to do that calculation in the main query, and operate much faster at the same time:

```
Update Amounts 
Left join Fx_rates on Amounts.Data=Fx_rates.Data
set Amt_lcy =  Amounts.Amt_fcy*Fx_rates.Rate
```